# Ubuntu disappeared from my boot screen

Tags: dual-boot, windows, wubi

I have triple boot (XP, 7, Ubuntu in Wubi) and today my Windows 7 got messed up and request I insert the installation CD and do a repair. When I did the repair, my boot screen got messed up and I no longer have Ubuntu to choose to boot from.

I have used EasyBCD to add XP back to the boot screen, but I couldn't use it to add Ubuntu back.

Comment: I have used the Boot Repair bootloader, but it did not solve the problem. If I run the Ubuntu installation again, will that fix the problem? Will that reset the software configurations I have made?

Comment: Yes, run the ubuntu installation directly from a live disk and do not install using wubi as it is not a recommended method of installation. See below.

Answer (score 1):

My Advice is for you to use the commandline commands from a console screen via the Live CD.

First boot to live CD.  Choose the Try Ubuntu option.  Enter the Terminal Console.  Then run these steps:

### Fix grup boot:

```
1) boot to the Ubuntu installation disk
2) Run the "Try Ubuntu" option
3) Bring up a terminal (Launch search "terminal")
4) Run these commands (exactly):

a) sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt  # Make "X" the partition that has Ubuntu installed (i.e. /dev/sda2).
b) for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt/$i"; done
c) sudo chroot /mnt
d) update-grub
e) if no errors skip this "e" section
    grub-install /dev/sdX (x is the hard drive that has linux installed (i.e. /dev/sda)
    update-grub
```

The key to your specific case is the "update-grub".  However, you have to have that installation active when you run it.  Therefore the other steps are important.

Comment: there is no grub to fix with wubi

Answer (score 0):

You have to reinstall the GRUB bootloader:

- Grab a USB stick and copy all of its files to the local hard disk
- Download the [Boot Repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) live CD
- Download and run [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) for Windows
- In UNetBootin: ([Offical Instructions](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/#install)) [image: Screenshot]

  - Select the `Diskimage` option (1)
  - Click on the `...` button and select the downloaded .iso file (2)
  - Select the drive letter of your USB device next to `Drive:` **Make sure its the right one!!!** (3)
  - Click `OK`
  - Wait for the process to complete
- Reboot
- During POST (when you see your hardware manufacturers logo) press `F12`, select your USB Stick (using arrow keys) and press `Enter`
- Within "Boot Repair": ([Official instructions](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/))

  - Choose your language,
  - Connect internet if possible
  - Click "Recommended repair"

Comment: I have already done all that and it did not work :(.........This is my Ubuntu Pastebin link.......... http://paste.ubuntu.com/7561275/

Comment: Ufff... You didn't say you were using Wubi. Try replacing your "<Windows 7 C:>/boot.ini" file with this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7566219/ (**Make a backup of that file first** and don't start EasyBCD) then reboot select "Windows XP" then select "Ubuntu". (I haven't used Wubi in a very long time so don't be disappointed if it doesn't work right away). Also: If it works do yourself a favour and migrate Ubuntu to its own partition.

Comment: Also try `/ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr` instead of `\wubildr` if it doesn't work

Comment: My Windows 7 bootloader is "\Windows\system32\winload.exe" , how will I add the boot.ini ?????

Comment: Wasn't taking about your Windows 7 bootloader... Quote: **[...]then reboot, select "Windows XP" [in the Windows 7 boot menu] then select "Ubuntu"**

Comment: You are so vague. I do not have a "boot.ini" file existing to replace to begin with! Where can I locate it?

Comment: did you gave up?

Comment: No, just AFK/in holidays ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay since this is about Wubi and you are using EasyBCD anyways:

1. Boot Windows 7
2. Start EasyBCD
   [image: Steps]

   1. On the right side select "Add new entry" (1)
   2. In the "Portable/External media" section select the image type "Raw Hard Disk Image" (2)
   3. Recommended: Enter a useful name
   4. Select the file `<Ubuntu installation path>\winboot\wubildr.mbr` as "Path" (3)
      In your case Ubuntu is *probably* installed in `E:\ubuntu` which would result in the path being `E:\ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr` - it might be slightly different however...
   5. Click "Add Entry" (4)
3. Reboot
4. In the Windows Boot menu select Ubuntu
5. **Hope**

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this is to scrap wubi and do a fresh install of Ubuntu to your hard drive from a live disk as the wubi method of installation is no longer recommended (for obvious reasons).

There are tons of youtube videos that can show you how to do this on a system with 3 or more partitioned operating systems.

Boot your computer from an Ubuntu Live Disk and select to try Ubuntu with out installing.

Use the gparted application to create a separate partition formatted to ext4 for your installation and another separate partition formatted to linux-swap that only needs to be 2-4GB.

Set up a working internet connection and then click on the install Ubuntu icon from the desktop.

When you get to the portion of the installation where it asks you what where and how to install Ubuntu, "along side" or to "replace Windows", go to the bottom and choose "something else".

From this screen, right-click on the ext4 partition you recently created. Choose the mount point "/"

Choose continue, yes to make changes, and continue with the rest of the installation.

Answer (score -2):

You Use Boot-Repair(https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

And use it to re-enable GRUB.
Just Follow the steps on the Help Page

Comment: he's using wubi within windows so there was no grub to begin with